# Exception when iterating through background nodes + checking string

Tags: swift, string

I'm iterating through the nodes of an SKNode. When I print all the child nodes belonging to bgNode, I get all of the names that I'm looking for (e.g. names containing "red").

However, when this code executes, the program quits, and I get: EXC_BREAKPOINT, even though I didn't put one there. It usually highlights the child.name?.contains("red") but if all it returns is a Bool value, then why is this happening?

```
   for child in bgNode.children {
        if (child.name?.contains("red"))! {
            let popUp = SKAction.moveBy(x: 0, y: 20, duration: 1.0)
            child.run(SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.sequence([wait])))
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
if let name = child.name, name.contains("red") {
    ...
}
```

> It usually highlights the child.name?.contains("red") but if all it returns is a Bool value, then why is this happening?

It happens because of `child.name?` could be nil and later you try to force unwrapping it: `child.name?.contains("red")!` - could be `(nil)!`, which is cause crash

Comment: Thank you for explaining it -- didn't check that the name wasn't nil!